# #AzureDataFactory & linked services. SQL Server connection error

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am facing below error while connecting on premise SQL Server database in Azure Data Factory. I was establish a self hosted integration IR which running fine. Any one help on this please.

> Cannot connect to SQL Database: '_********&', Database: '********', User: '________'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
>
> Cannot open server '____&' requested by the login. Client with IP address '223.196.174.128' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect., SqlErrorNumber=40615,Class=14,State=1,
> Activity ID: _____________.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Client with IP address '223.196.174.128' is not allowed to access the server.

That's not an error you'll ever get from an On-Prem SQL Server.  That error is coming from Azure SQL Database, and it means exactly what it says.  Your client IP is not allowed to connect in the [Server's Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql).